# Git alias to open the git installation folder

Tags: windows, bash, git, git-bash, explorer

I want to create a git alias `git dir`, which when used should open the git installation folder via Windows Explorer, how to implement such an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using Git Bash, try:

```sh
git config --global alias.dir '!start "" "$(git --exec-path)"'
```

Reference: [Can I use the "start" command with spaces in the path?](https://superuser.com/a/239572/1023031)

Answer (score 1):

Starting an alias with ! treats it as a command.

I don't have a windows machine at hand, but for Linux:

```
git config --global alias.open '!git --exec-path | xargs xdg-open'
```

Works as described.

So the command you're looking for will probably look something like:

```
git config --global alias.open "!git --exec-path | 'sed s~/~\\~g' | xargs explorer"
```

Comment: @WenfangDu: That probably means that the \ characters are getting swallowed somehow - try putting \\\\ instead of \\.